# general solution of equation and relation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am interested in learning the below question in some elementary way. Please discuss this problem and help me to get mind free state.

How to get solutions for $x^2 - 10y^2$ = $1$? I would like to learn some easy method. Also, I have seen in some text book $x= 19$ and $y = 6$ is one of the solution and general solution can be prepared by using $x = 19$ and  $y = 6$ in terms of $n$. where $n$ is some positive integer. Please explain this general solution and relation with $x = 19$ and $y =6$.

Advance thanks to all.

Comment: You will be interested in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation).

Comment: @plz answer... I could not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is known as Pell's equation.

This is how to find all solutions in an elementary way.

$$x^2-10y^2=1$$ can be factored to give $$(x+\sqrt{10}y)(x-\sqrt{10}y)=1$$

You can find more solutions by taking $(19+\sqrt{10}6)$ to some integer power, collecting like terms and putting $y$ equal to the coefficient of $\sqrt{10}$ and $x$ to the integer part of the result. These will always be solutions because $1^k=1$ and because the binomial theorem confirms that the absolute value of the negative term in the second bracket will always be equal to the value of $\sqrt{10}y$.

Note we have not shown that this is a complete set of solutions. That is much harder to do, and not as elementary as you would probably want. If you do want an explanation however, just leave a comment below.

Why $$x=\frac{(x+\sqrt{10}y)^n+(x-\sqrt{10}y)^n}{2}$$ is always a solution:

We know from the above that $x$ is integer part of $(19+\sqrt{10} \cdot 6)^n$.

Note that in the expansion of $(x+\sqrt{10}y)^n+(x-\sqrt{10}y)^n$ all the irrational terms cancel out (by the binomial theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). What is left is twice the required coefficient so we divide by 2 to get $x$.

Comment: ! Thank you so much for your wonderful explanation. But, I want to know how we got 19 and 6 for x and y values? Please explain.

Comment: ! I will try in my level best for understand your solution and you try in your level best to produce your solution in elementary way. I want to know how we get x = 19 and y = 6. How to make general solution by using x = 19, y = 6 and some n, where n is  belongs to positive integer.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no set elementary way to find the first solution upon which all the others are built. You can create computer programs to do it (excel would be an elementary). The best way to do it for simple(ish) cases like the one you had is to simply try possibilities. For this one you would try $y=1$ $11$ is not square, $y=2$, but $41$ is not square, $y=3,4,5$ don't work but $y=6$ gives $x^2=361$ $\implies x=19$. Then you can build on this using the method I described above. Let me know if you need any further explanation.

Comment: ! fine. By trail and error we got x = 19 and y = 6. How to get x = [(19 + 6 square root of 10)^n+ (19-6 square root of 10)^n]/2 and similarly for y. How can we write this type of general solution with by our known x = 19 and y = 6?

Comment: I'll explain how to get this $x = [(19 + 6 \sqrt{10})^n+ (19-6 \sqrt10)^n]/2$ in an edit to my answer.

Comment: ! in your edited post please take n = 3. Then you will get x= x^3 + 30xy^2, which is wrong. I juts taken in place of n by 3 and then I used binomial theorem. Then your formula not working. Please check

Comment: ! if you take n = 2, also not working.

Comment: take n = 2, then we have; [(x + y.square root 10)^2+ (x - y. square root 10)^2]/2 = x^2 + 10 y^2. This is not equal to x. If you take either n = 0 or n = 1, we get x. I.e., this formula is failed.Please explain where I am wrong, if I am wrong.

Comment: sorry for n = 0 is wrong case. It is working only for n = 1.

Comment: It actually is working, but it only works for x=19 and y=6 if you want a more general solution let $10=d$.

Comment: Let x=19 and y=6 in the cube case then you get x'=27379 which is the x term of the next solution. The equation IS working.

Comment: ! Forget about x = 19 and y = 6 for time being. Then put n = 2 in our edited equation, you get x = x^2 + 10 y^2. But, we have to get x = x.

Comment: ! even if you take x = 19 and y = 6 and n =3, you get x dash = 27379. But as for formula you have to divide with 2. Then you will get x answer in fractions.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. WE DON'T WANT X=X!. In my notation I should have called the new x, $x_1$ or $x'$. Also, if $x'$ is the second solution to the equation the formula only works for the x^2-10y^2=1 equation if you want it to work for all x^2-dy^2=1 replace all the tens in the formula with d's.

Comment: YOu do not get x in fractions you have already divided by 2!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: ! I am extremely so sorry. You are very much correct and now I got (yes we divided by 2) It is ok. If you can clear the my last and final one, we can close this discussions. if we take n= 2, without taking x = 19 an y = 6, we get x = x^2 + 10y^2. Why? This is my last question. Please...

Comment: If you aren't looking at the equation $x^2-10y^2=1$ but instead looking at the equation $x^2-dy^2=1$ where 19 and 16 aren't solutions first you find a base solution $x_1, y_1$ then all other solutions are given by $$x'=\frac{(x_1+\sqrt{d}y_1)^n+(x_1-\sqrt{d}y_1)^n}{2}$$ So if $n=2$, $$x'=x_1^2+dy_1^2$$. this is why $x'=x^2+10y^2$ doesn't always work, because d is the variable and when $d=10$ we have x=19, y=6 but this is not always the case. Don't hesitate to ask about anything further. :)

Comment: ! thank you so much for your patiance. Today, i got full undrestandig on this area by your support. i cannot for get ur help. if u dont mind, please provide ur emai id here or sehd ur emaid to dr.madmath@rediffmail.com

Comment: Why do you want me to do that?

Comment: ! i just becomme a big fan of u

Comment: OK, I'll send it through. I'm very glad you understand this topic now and glad I could help.

Comment: ! bye I am waiting for your Id in my ID. Thanks again. bye bye...

Answer (score 0):

We add a few comments. First we should mention the Brahmagupta Identity, which for this case is 
$$(s^2-10t^2)(u^2-10v^2)=(st+10uv)^2-10(sv+tu)^2.\tag{$1$}$$
This identity can be verified by expanding both sides.

From this identity, if we have a representation of $m$ in the form $x^2-10y^2$, and also a representation of $n$ of that form, then the identity gives us a representation of $mn$.

$(1.)$ In particular, let $s=u=3$ and $t=v=1$. Then $s^2-10t^2=-1$. Thus by the Brahmagupta Identity, we have
$$(s^2-10t^2)(s^2-10t^2)=(9+10)^2-10(3+3)=(-1)(-1)=1.$$
Thus the solution $(19,6)$ can be thought of as coming from the simpler "almost" solution $(3,1)$.

$(2.)$ Let $a_1=19$, $b_1=6$. For $n\ge 1$, define $a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}$ by
$$a_{n+1}=19a_n+6b_n,\qquad\text{and}\qquad b_{n+1} =6a_n+ 19b_n.\tag{$2$}$$
The recurrences $(2)$ give an easy way to produce more solutions of our equation $x^2-10y^2=1$. For example, $(a_2,b_2)=(721,228)$.

It turns out that all positive solutions come from the recurrence $(2)$.

$(3.)$ You asked how one obtains $(19,6)$, the **fundamental** solution. There is a mechanical and relatively quick way of doing it, using the *continued fraction* expansion of $\sqrt{10}$. Computations can be arranged so that they are pure *integer* computations, meaning we do not need to know anything about the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{10}$.

There is a very nice book on the Pell equation by Ed Barbeau. Many number theory texts discuss the Pell equation in detail.